Creating a wavy border on all sides using CSS
Using this generator I can create the wavy border I'm after on either the top and bottom or left and right, but I'm having trouble combining these masks to create a wavy border all the way around.
Top and Bottom


.box {
background-color: aqua;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
  --mask:
    radial-gradient(78.75px at 50% 111px,#000 99%,#0000 101%) calc(50% - 120px) 0/240px 51% repeat-x,
    radial-gradient(78.75px at 50% -51px,#0000 99%,#000 101%) 50% 60px/240px calc(51% - 60px) repeat-x,
    radial-gradient(78.75px at 50% calc(100% - 111px),#000 99%,#0000 101%) calc(50% - 120px) 100%/240px 51% repeat-x,
    radial-gradient(78.75px at 50% calc(100% + 51px),#0000 99%,#000 101%) 50% calc(100% - 60px)/240px calc(51% - 60px) repeat-x;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
}
<div class="box"></div>



Left and Right


.box {
background-color: aqua;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
 --mask:
    radial-gradient(78.75px at 111px 50%,#000 99%,#0000 101%) 0 calc(50% - 120px)/51% 240px repeat-y,
    radial-gradient(78.75px at -51px 50%,#0000 99%,#000 101%) 60px 50%/calc(51% - 60px) 240px repeat-y,
        radial-gradient(78.75px at calc(100% - 111px) 50%,#000 99%,#0000 101%) 100% calc(50% - 120px)/51% 240px repeat-y,
    radial-gradient(78.75px at calc(100% + 51px) 50%,#0000 99%,#000 101%) calc(100% - 60px) 50%/calc(51% - 60px) 240px repeat-y;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
}
<div class="box"></div>




I have made it here: https://css-shape.com/wavy-box/


.wavy-box {
  --s: 35px;  /* control the size of the wave */
  --w: 350px; /* preferred  width */
  --c:#CD8C52;
  
  width: round(var(--w),2*var(--s)); 
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  padding: var(--s);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: calc(1.5*var(--s));
  --R:calc(var(--s)/sqrt(2)) at;
  --g:radial-gradient(var(--R) 50%,var(--c) calc(100% - 1px),#0000) 
     0 0/calc(2*var(--s)) calc(2*var(--s));
  --_c:#0000 100%,var(--c) calc(100% + 1px);
  --_b:calc(2*var(--s)) calc(51% - var(--s)/2) repeat-x;
  background: var(--g),
    radial-gradient(var(--R) 50% calc(100% + var(--s)/2),var(--_c)) 
     var(--s) calc(100% - var(--s)/2)/var(--_b),
    radial-gradient(var(--R) 50% calc(      var(--s)/-2),var(--_c)) 
     var(--s) calc(       var(--s)/2)/var(--_b);
  --_m:var(--s)/calc(51% - var(--s)/2) calc(2*var(--s)) repeat-y;
  mask: var(--g),
    radial-gradient(var(--R) calc(100% + var(--s)/2) 50%,var(--_c))
     calc(100% - var(--s)/2) var(--_m),
    radial-gradient(var(--R) calc(      var(--s)/-2) 50%,var(--_c)) 
     calc(       var(--s)/2) var(--_m);
}
/* if round() is not supported we work with an increment method */
@supports not (opacity:round(1,1)) {
  .wavy-box {
    --n: 5;
    width: calc(var(--n)*2*var(--s));
  }
}
<div class="wavy-box"></div>



If you want a version with gradient coloration check this link where I am using a more complex configuration: https://css-tip.com/image-wavy-borders-2/
